# recover my compressed files from the servers with the javascript get method

Tags: javascript, php

please I am a beginner,
So here I have a mini app where the user (client side) sends a zip file through a form, then the program decompresses it and sends it to the server (in an upload folder, with the POST method and a small code from php). it works well and in the server there are the decompressed files. but here it is that I block I would like to recover them with GET with Javascript in order to recover them the data of the files and contunier my code with javascript.
Here is my code, I wrote the URL to the (upload) folder in get but I don't know how to tell it that it brings me back the files that it has just decompressed for me.

thank you for those who will try to help me.

```js
var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"),
 oData = new FormData(form);
console.log(oData);
oData.append("CustomField", oData.get("file"));
console.log(oData);
   oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   console.log(location.href);
  oReq.open("POST", "stash.php", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      
      console.log(oData);
     // console.log(oReq);
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(oData.get("file"));
        console.log(oData.get("file").name);
       // console.log(oData.get("upload/?C=D;O=D").name);
      
    
                        myFunction(this);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET","upload/"+??????????, true);
               
                xhttp.send();
} else {
      oOutput.innerHTML = "Erreur " + oReq.status +
     "lors de la tentative d’envoi du fichier.<br\/>";
     }
  };
  oReq.send(oData);
  console.log(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
  
        
function myFunction(xml) {
  
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  
 console.log(xmlDoc);

};
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" name="fileinfo" id="formParcourir"> 
     <label></label>
        <input type="file" name="file" required class="envoyez"  />
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyez" class="envoyez"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recover"? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hello thank you for your answer ,  then I would like to retrieve from the server (upload folder) the files which have just been unzipped and send them to my JS functions and display them

Comment: @NicoHaase knowing that it is XML files

Comment: so to clarify: Your client / user will send a zip file containing XML files to the server where the server is to decompress / unzip them. Once unzipped PHP should read the XML and return that to your AJAX callback?

Comment: If reading zipped files is too hard, why not send unzipped files? Or use gzip for transfer encryption of a single file?

Comment: @ProfesseurAbronsius no php just unzipped them and sent them to the folder now it's up to javascript to retrieve the files from the folder (upload) and display them in the function (in ajax)

Comment: @NicoHaase the files have been unzipped what i would like now is to get the unzipped files from the upload folder and display them in my function (this)

Comment: OK - I understand your comment. PHP unzips and saves the files - but you should NOT make a second request using GET to read these unzipped files because of the asynchronous nature of AJAX. This can be done in a single operation unless of course this `read` is to be done at a later date/time but if so why the nested ajax call above?

Comment: @ProfesseurAbronsius it was unzipped by php, and the unzipped files are in the upload folder, now i want to recover them only

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the decompressed files are in my folder (upload), I want to access and recover the files to display them in my function

Comment: And what's your question about this? If the decompressed files are present in a public folder, why not read them?

Comment: @ProfesseurAbronsius 
I would like to display the files, so what do I do please?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to display the file names (in a list perhaps) or the contents from these uploaded XML files?

Comment: @NicoHaase 
I don't know how to display them on my function, this is where I need help, I know how to do it when it is a single file but not two

Comment: @ProfesseurAbronsius exactly, both if possible

Comment: @NicoHaase read files

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius read files

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a clarified version of your question. What's the exact problem with "read files"? If they are already stored uncompressed on the server, why is that compression relevant for your question? Also, if this question is in any way related to PHP itself, please share the relevant parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the requirement here but do not understand why there are two separate AJAX requests to completely different endpoints when it could, as far as I can tell, be done with a single request. Below is a single page demo that has worked OK in testing here which will hopefully help.

No checking of uploaded file type is done here nor any error checking. Save a copy and run on own webserver to test.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        /*
            extract key information about the 
            uploaded ZIP file
        */
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $name=$obj->name;
        
        /*
            Output will be appended to this
            variable and sent to the ajax 
            callback.
        */
        $data=array();
        
        /*
            set & create if necessary critical 
            directory structure
        */
        $dir=sprintf('%s/uploads',__DIR__);
        if( !file_exists( $dir ) )mkdir( $dir, 0777, true );
        
        $xmldir=sprintf('%s/xml',$dir);
        if( !file_exists( $xmldir ) )mkdir( $xmldir, 0777, true );
        
        /*
            create suitable relative path for 
            hyperlinks.
        */
        $filepath=ltrim( str_replace( '\\', '/', str_replace( realpath( getcwd() ), '', realpath( $xmldir ) ) ), '/' );

        
        /*
            Save the XML file
        */
        $target=sprintf( '%s/%s', $dir, $name );
        move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );
        
        /*
            Open the Zipfile and process it
        */
        $zip=new ZipArchive;
        $res=$zip->open( $target );
        if( $res===true ){
            /*
                extract the files to sub-directory
            */
            $status=$zip->extractTo( $xmldir );
            
            for( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ){
                $file=$zip->getNameIndex( $i );
                $data[ $file ]=array(
                    'path'      =>  sprintf('%s/%s', $filepath, $file ),
                    'xml'       =>  $zip->getFromName( $file ),
                    'extracted' =>  $status,
                    'index'     =>  $i,
                    'total'     =>  $zip->numFiles
                );
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Upload Zipped XML Files, unzip, read and send to ajax callback</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
                
                const form=document.forms.fileinfo;
                const bttn=form.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
                const ul=document.querySelector('ul');
                const output=document.querySelector('output');
                
                const clickhandler=function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let fd=new FormData( form );
                        
                    fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
                        .then( r=>{ return r.json() } )
                        .then( json=>{
                            
                            Object.keys(json).forEach( key=>{
                                /*
                                    Create and append new link
                                */
                                let li=document.createElement('li');
                                let a=document.createElement('a');
                                    a.href=json[key].path;
                                    a.innerHTML=key;
                                    a.target='_blank';
                                    
                                li.append( a );
                                ul.appendChild( li );
                                /*
                                    Fetch does not natively read/process XML
                                    so additional steps to actually read and 
                                    process the XML correctly are required.
                                    
                                    Here the raw data is simply output to
                                    the page - no parsing is done.
                                    
                                    Hint: DOMParser & parseFromString
                                    
                                    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
                                */
                                output.textContent += json[ key ].xml;
                            })
                        })                      
                };
                
                bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler );
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='fileinfo' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'> 
            <input type='file' name='file' class='envoyez' required />
            <input type='submit' value='Envoyez' class='envoyez' />
        </form>
        
        <ul></ul>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```